Formie or Freeform include current page title in submissions and email notifications
I have not decided on which particular plugin to use yet, but i've been all over the docs for both Freeform and Formie trying to find a way to 'capture' the current page title and include it in both the form submission AND the email notifications.  If this is at all possible, could someone please tell me how it's done (step-by-step)?
Thanks

There are a few different ways of doing this in Freeform (not familiar with Formie yet, sorry), but perhaps the most robust is to do it via your templates:

Add a hidden field to your form in the form editor in the control panel.
Populate that field's value via the overrideValues parameter of the form method in your template that displays the form. Specifically for your use case it'd look something like this

{% set form = craft.freeform.form('yourFormHandle', {
    overrideValues: {
        yourHiddenFieldHandle: entry.title ?? 'None'
    }
}) %}

Since it's just an ordinary field, you can then output its value the same way as a plain text field for the purposes of your email notifications.
